# How to break execution of event method

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a event handling method like this:

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Some code
if (int.TryParse(tboxPhone.Text, out n))
    {
     korisnik.Phone = n;
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", korisnik.Phone);
    }
    else
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Error. Numerals only!");
     return;
    }
//Some other code if condition is fulfilled
}
```

Problem is return not only breaks from method, but entire form. I could live with this, but it is not the best solution. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: `return` will leave the current method, you should debug to take a closer look at this.

Comment: what exactly do you mean it "breaks from ... entire form?" does your application crash? does the form stop working?

Comment: probably there is some close method afther the event, and when you returning, it executes

Comment: I just did. Problem is 'try{}catch{}finally{}' statement. When it breaks, it goes to 'finally' block where it exits. I transfered Close() from finally block and now it works fine. Thanks @Andre Calil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw what's the problem. `if` statement was inside `try-catch` block, and when it returns, it goes directly to `finally` block.

I just transfered `Close();` from `finally` block, and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `return` completely e.g.

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    //Some code 
    if (int.TryParse(tboxPhone.Text, out n)) 
    { 
        korisnik.Telefon = n; 
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", korisnik.Telefon); 
        //Some other code if condition is fulfilled 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Error. Numerals only!");  
    } 
}
```

Comment: *"Just get rid of the return completel"*  Why? What is wrong with OP's code. The problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: @L.B. Simply because there is no need to call it. There should be no need to jump out early, I have suggested re-writing the code to let the event exit naturally (I have moved the OP's original comment to inside the if condition).

Answer (score 0):

You should do the numeric validation on keypress instead.. this way your code will never go in the 'else' and it is a better way to handle your validation at the same time.

```
private void tboxPhone_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Also regex is a way:

```
private void tboxPhone_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "\\d+"))
          e.Handled = true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does this answer  *"Problem is return not only breaks from method, but entire form"* ?

Comment: @L.B With my method, it is a better way to do his validation first, and at the same time it will never go in the return because the int.TryParse will be always successfull